# Is there any way in c++ to make sure at compile time a non-template function is not used anywhere?

Tags: c++, function, compilation

So I know I can see whether a function is called either after compilation (using disassembly and -O0 usually) or at runtime by introducing an exception into it.

However I'm interested in making sure a particular function (in this case operator new) is never called from anywhere? I want to make sure I do not perform any dynamic memory allocation at compile time.

A warning would probably suffice that the function is used.

UPDATE:

A code example is here:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// replace operator new and delete to log allocations
void* operator new (std::size_t n) {
    std::cout << "Allocating " << n << " bytes" << std::endl;
    return malloc(n);
}
void operator delete(void* p) throw() {
    free(p);
}

  class TestPlate
  {
    private:
        int value;

    public:
        int getValue(){ return value; }
        void setValue(int newValue) { value = newValue; }

        int doStuff(const std::function<int()>& stuff) { return stuff(); }

  };

int main()
{
    TestPlate testor;
    testor.setValue(15);
    const std::function<int()>& func =  std::bind(&TestPlate::getValue, &testor);

    std::cout << testor.doStuff(func) << std::endl;
}
```

I would like to receive an error whenever anything tries to use operator new. In this case the internals of std::function try to use operator new.

In general I want to make sure that my program does not perform any sort of dynamic memory allocation. I want to be sure of that at compile time.

Comment: I could imagine template meta programming techniques, but well your requirements aren't very clear from your post. A code example of what you want to achive would be great.

Comment: Edit your question and add code to it, dont provide just external links.

Comment: Added the sample code directly

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be 100% sure a function is never called, then delete it. Then the compiler and linker will yell at you if something did indeed try to call it.

Comment: I tried doing that however that results in compiler errors like: 11:64: error: deleted definition of 'void* operator new(std::size_t)' so this might work with functions that aren't overwritten but not with functions whose declaration is being shadowed

Comment: Indeed, it seems that this technique will work for most functions but not for `::operator new`...

Comment: Please provide a more detailed description of what you want to achieve and a code example. Then perhaps better answers can be given.

Answer (score 1):

How about class-specific operator new and make it private? I.e.:

```
class MyClass {
...
private:
    void * operator new(size_t size);
};
```

Then when trying to call `new MyClass`, the compiler should complain.

**EDIT:**

So another solution might be to make the call of `operator new` ambiguous. For example:

```
// make the call to operator new ambiguous
struct Invalid {};
void * operator new(size_t size, Invalid inv = Invalid());
```

After doing this, every call of the `operator new` will be ambiguous (because the second parameter has a default value, so the compiler will not know, which version to use). And with your example, it then fails to compile the `std::function` template.

Comment: That does work if you use operator new on classes. However it would not catch dynamic allocation of class members like: int[] a = new int[20];

Comment: See the edit - it seems this can be "solved" by making (every) call of `operator new` ambiguous.